# highcharter: how can I customize the labels on a column plot

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to make a highcharts plot similar to this (made with ggplot):
[image]

This code comes close, but I am uncertain how to change the label to indicate the `games` rather than the win_rate.

```
data = data.frame(player = c('Edwin', 'Ahmad', 'Sonia', 'Jessica'),
                  games = c(10, 20, 15, 40),
                  win_rate = c(.5, .2, .8, .4))




highchart() %>%
      highcharter::hc_chart(type = 'column', zoomType = 'x') %>%
      highcharter::hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal'))  %>%
      highcharter::hc_xAxis(categories = data$player) %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series(name = 'Win Rate', 
                                 data = data$win_rate,  
                                 dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, verticalAlign = 'top'))
```

How can I swap out the default labels with labels of my own choosing?

Comment: The first plot was made in ggplot to illustrate what I am trying to do with highcharter. I edited to make that clearer. So I am trying make a column plot where column heights show the win rate but the label (e.g. "40") would show how many games they have played. My code shows the win_rate instead. I do not believe your suggestions do this.

Comment: Sounds like you want to plot win rate on the vertical axis, but the label should show different information (# of games) --- is that right?

Comment: correct, just like the plot I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would pass your whole `data` dataframe into `data` argument in `hc_add_series` then you can reference in your `dataLabels` in `format`:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$player) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = data, type = 'column', hcaes(x = player, y = win_rate),
                dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}'))
```

[image: plot with custom labels in highcharter]

Comment: thanks, that does the trick. I guess I need to figure out how to use hcaes properly since I hope to add stacks and groups to this as well.